# Lenovo IdeaPad laptop doesn't wake up after suspend

Tags: debian, suspend, laptop, hibernate, amd-graphics

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 320 laptop with Debian testing/buster and Linux 4.18.5. When I close the lid and open it again, the screen is black, and I can't do anything. I can't even ctrl-alt-F3 to a vterm. At this point I need to restart the laptop every time I close the lid.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to fix this? I have `CONFIG_SUSPEND=y` set in my kernel. I'm using the amdgpu video card drivers with kernel modesetting enabled.